# ¿comó se podría colocar un carousel de bootstrap con loop utilizando Django?

Tags: html, python, bootstrap, django, bootstrap-carousel

Saludos estoy tratando de hacer un carousel de bootstrap 5 con múltiples items en django. Pero al momento de renderizar la pagina, se queda en el primer intems y no cumple con la animacion. El fragmento de cogigo es el siguiente:

¿como se haria para que imprima solo los 3 primeros items?

```html
  {% for post in publica %}
  <div id="myCarousel{{ post }}" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-indicators">
      {% if forloop.first %}
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel{{ post }}" data-bs-slide-to="{{ post }}" class="active"
        aria-current="true" aria-label="{{ post }}"></button>
      {% else %}
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel{{ post }}" data-bs-slide-to="{{ post }}"
        aria-label="{{ post.counter }}"></button>
      {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      {% if forloop.first %}
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        {% else %}
        <div class="carousel-item">
          {% endif %}
          <img src="{{post.imagen.url}}" alt="..." class="d-inline-block">
          <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
              <h1>{{ post.titulo }}</h1>
              <p>{{ post.resumen }}</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel{{ post }}" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel{{ post }}" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

y la información le llega de la siguiente forma:

```
def home(request):
publi =post.objects.filter(publicado=True)

return render(request, 'proyecto_web_app/home.html',{'publica':publi})
```

de antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Que te devuelve por consola si haces un print(publi) antes del return ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estás cometiendo un error al crear el carrousel dentro del template tag {% for post in publica %} {% endfor %}. La estructura que deberías seguir es más o menos la siguiente (debería funcionar):

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
   <ol class="carousel-indicators">
     {% for i in images %}
     <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="{{ forloop.counter0 }}" {% if forloop.first %}class="active"{% endif %}></li>
     {% endfor %}
   </ol>
   <div class="carousel-inner">
       {% for image in images %}
       <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}">
           <img class="d-block w-100" src="{{ image.url }}" alt="{{ image.title }}">
           <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
              <h5>{{ image.title }}</h5>
              <p>{{ image.description }}</p>
           </div>
       </div>
       {% endfor %}
   </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
   </a>
   <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
   </a>
</div>
```